# Launch my App following connection with a specific Bluetooth device

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I would like my application to be launched by the iOS system when a specific Bluetooth device connects itself to the iPhone.

Do you know if it exists a iOS service for which an app can register itself in order it's launched when a Bluetooth connection is detected ?

Thank you very much for your help
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to be written in the bluetooth device, not in the iPhone.
I am developing application with this system, and it's not clearly written in my app. The iPhone check the Array : Supported external accessory protocols only and if it matches with the procotol in the bluetooth device...

Comment: This doesn't look like a clear answer. In the future please use the comments on the question and only post an answer when you have a definitive solution to the problem.